# Replace rows in a Pandas df with rows from another df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 Pandas dfs, A and B. Both have 10 columns and the index 'ID'. Where the IDs of A and B match, I want to replace the rows of B with the rows of A. I have tried to use pd.update, but no success yet. Any help appreciated.

Comment: try `A.combine_first(B)` should work.See [how to make a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: If you update rows of B with rows of A the same result will come? not clear can you provide an example of expected output

Comment: Marlon: No, A and B contain some matching IDs, but the contents of the other columns is different.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

below code should do the trick

```
s1 = pd.Series([5, 1, 'a'])
s2 = pd.Series([6, 2, 'b'])
s3 = pd.Series([7, 3, 'd'])
s4 = pd.Series([8, 4, 'e'])
s5 = pd.Series([9, 5, 'f'])



df1 = pd.DataFrame([list(s1), list(s2),list(s3),list(s4),list(s5)],  columns =  ["A", "B", "C"])

s1 = pd.Series([5, 6, 'p'])
s2 = pd.Series([6, 7, 'q'])
s3 = pd.Series([7, 8, 'r'])
s4 = pd.Series([8, 9, 's'])
s5 = pd.Series([9, 10, 't'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([list(s1), list(s2),list(s3),list(s4),list(s5)],  columns =  ["A", "B", "C"])

df1.loc[df1.A.isin(df2.A), ['B', 'C']] = df2[['B', 'C']]
print df1
```

output

```
   A   B  C
0  5   6  p
1  6   7  q
2  7   8  r
3  8   9  s
4  9  10  t
```

Edit from comments:

To replace the whole row instead of only some columns:

```
cols = list(df1.columns) 
df1.loc[df1.A.isin(df2.A), cols] = df2[cols]
```

Comment: Old question but what if I want to replace the whole row instead of some columns?

Comment: @ Rafael Almeida I assume that you have same set columns in both dataframes; Try this;             cols = list(df1.columns)
df1.loc[df1.A.isin(df2.A), cols] = df2[cols]

Comment: the last line `df1.loc[df1.A.isin(df2.A), ['B', 'C']] = df2[['B', 'C']]` produce `NaN` for me. I need to ad `.values` in the assigned values. It becomes `df1.loc[df1.A.isin(df2.A), ['B', 'C']] = df2[['B', 'C']].values`

Answer (score 2):

You can empty your target cells in *A* (by setting them to NaN) and use the [`combine_first()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) method to fill those with *B*'s values. Although it may sound counter-intuitive, this approach gives you the flexibility to both target rows and specific columns in 2 lines of code. Hope that helps.

An example replacing the full row's that have an index match:

```py
# set-up
cols = ['c1','c2','c3']
A = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(9).reshape((3,3)), columns=cols)
B = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10,16).reshape((2,3)), columns=cols)

#solution
A.loc[B.index] = np.nan
A = A.combine_first(B)
```

An example of only replacing certain target columns for row's that have an index match:

```py
A.loc[B.index, ['c2','c3']] = np.nan
A = A.combine_first(B)
```

Comment: Regarding the `SettingWithCopyWarning` resulting from using [`.loc()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html). It is my understanding that you can safely ignore it when you intend to overwrite the original DataFrame *A*. Not entirely sure if that is the case for this question. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas#answer-20627316) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Above code works based on the index value.
If we have different row counts for both data frame. It will not work.
For that, we need to set a specific column to index